# Freshly Installed Ubuntu 20.10 freezes abruptly with HP pavilion - AMD Ryzen 5 4600H - Nvidia Graphics 1650

Tags: ubuntu, grub, amd-radeon, nvidia-geforce, display-driver

I installed ubuntu 20.10 on HP pavilion laptop in dual boot with windows 10 home.
I am able to login to ubuntu but it randomly freezes after some time and I need to do a hard reset to restart.

The problem occur mostly when playing videos on youtube but can happen even without playing any video. Most of the time first thing that happen is that all the icons turns into file icons and after few seconds the OS is frozen.

I have tried the following options but none of them worked.

option 1: setting `nomodeset` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable in `/etc/default/grub` file

option 2: setting `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable in `/etc/default/grub` file

option 3: Installed different version of nvidia drivers through 'software update' GUI of ubuntu. The version tried were nvidia-driver-440, 450, 455, nvidia-server-driver-440. Also tried nouveau drivers, but none of them worked.

option 4: tried to install nvidia driver using command line.

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*

sudo apt install <name of nvidia driver>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a disaster.  A Ryzen 7 4800H with an NVidia 1660, the NVidia is impossible to use.  Tried every possible combination of nouveau or nvidia drivers.  The only solution is to blacklist the drivers for the NVidia and make do with the Ryzen's graphics.  They'll do for Youtube.

I've bought this system after being in the same situation with an MSI GTX70 "gaming" laptop.  With Linux, the dedicated graphics couldn't be used.  I thought, this time that won't be the case, I'll go for NVidia - which is great on the desktop.

Comment: Thanks Gerard, how can I blacklist nvidia driver?

Comment: You can simply uninstall them, but otherwise, you create a file /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf with the line "blacklist nvidia".  Idem for "nouveau".   The driver you need is the "amdgpu".